# Google is indexing a useless page for each image uploaded to my WordPress site

Tags: google, wordpress, url, search-engine-indexing, images

I found that when I create a blog post and insert images, WordPress automatically generates page for each one. When I check index status in Google with a `site:` search, I see 4 to 5 or more pages for my main article URL and all the images.

What can I do about this problem?

[image]

These pages compete with each other in Google search results for one keyword.  I'm worried that they could be hurting my SEO.

Answer (score 3):

That feature of WordPress isn't very useful and can create SEO problems.  It is however easy to deal with with extensions.   The Yoast SEO WordPress extension [has a solution](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/redirect-image-attachment-urls/).   You can have that extension redirect those pages to the image itself.

1. Install the Yoast SEO plugin
2. Click on 'SEO'
3. Click on 'Search Appearance'
4. Click on the 'Media' tab.
5. Ensure 'Redirect attachment URLs to the attachment itself?' is set to 'Yes'

The next time Google crawls those image page URLs, it will see the redirects and they will get deindexed shortly.   It may take Google a couple months to deindex all such pages across your entire site.

Comment: tnx stephen we do it and now image redirect to wp content and we hope goolge remove old urls at the next

Comment: If google has already indexed "media" pages, you might need to also run Yoast SEO: Search Index Purge plugin. What it does is nicely explained at plugin official page:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/yoast-seo-search-index-purge/